# ActionScript 2.0 button onclick not working

Tags: flash, events, button, actionscript, event-handling

this seems simple, but i'm new to AS 2.0 and I have a problem regarding button click event.

So I create a symbol->button then designed the button. I put it on the stage, right click it, and open actions tab.

I typed this code here :

```
_root.onMouseDown=function(){
    trace('button clicked');
}
```

then I play the movie (ctrl+enter), but when I clicked the button, the trace function doesn't executed (no output at all) and there's no error.

for some reasons, I can't use AS 3.0.... THX for any help...

Answer (score 0):

You say you put the code on the button but you are referencing _root for the event, unless that is the instance name of the button?

If I may suggest, you might find it easier and find the code more manageable as development progresses (not to mention easier to find and debug) to put your code on the timeline rather than instances of things like buttons, I normally use a layer and call it 'scripts'. I would suggest giving the button an instance name for example 'myButton' and then put the code on the timeline instead with this

```
myButton.onMousedown=function(){
    trace("button clicked");
}
```

I would also suggest that instead of the onMouseDown event you might want to use something like onClick instead.

Hope this helps,
Peter

Comment: the trace function still doesn't show the output. I've named the object 'play_button' and added play_button.onMouseDown on the frame, but it still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing the code on the button, you should use the onClipEvent function :

```
onClipEvent (release){
     trace ('button clicked');
}
```

But I still recommend that you put the code into the same frame as the above post. Helps you keep track of all the code.

Comment: i've tried it, but the trace function didn't print anything to output panel